# Why Google Translate translate back not same as the first time I translate?

Tags: google-translate

I translated "How to use Web?" but if I translate it back to English, it is not the same as first time I translate this.

[Linked to On-Topic question on Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/26845/why-dont-you-get-back-the-original-text-when-you-use-translation-software-to-tr)

Comment: This isn't about using Google Translate, but rather about language translation. As such it's not on-topic for [webapps.se]. It _may_ be on-topic at [linguistics.se].

Comment: Yes it is on-topic. I've tried asking a year before and now confirmed no one wants to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's not how languages work. Languages rarely have a one-to-one relationship to a word or phrase. We just get "close enough", based on context, to convey the same idea. Further, other languages have different rules about word order, punctuation, etc. There's really no way, except for the simplest sentences, for a machine to take a phrase, translate it to one language, then translate it back and restore the original phrase.

All that said, this isn't really a question about using Google Translate, but rather about translation in general.